# Rayon fold into a HashMap

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<Result<MyStruct, ()>>`, and I want to put them into buckets inside a HashMap, where keys are `MyStruct.b` field and values are a Vec containing all the MyStructs with that `MyStruct.b` field (see playground link below, might be clearer). I'm using fold, and it works with a normal `.fold`

```
let my_array = vec![Ok(m1), Ok(m2), Ok(m3), Err(())];

let result: HashMap<String, Vec<&MyStruct>> = my_array
    .iter()
    .filter_map(|value| value.as_ref().ok())
    .fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, value| {
        acc.entry(value.b.clone()).or_insert(vec![]).push(&value);
        acc
    });
```

However, I can't achieve the same with rayon

```
let my_array = vec![Ok(m1), Ok(m2), Ok(m3), Err(())];

let result = my_array
    .par_iter()
    .filter_map(|value| value.as_ref().ok())
    .fold(
        ||HashMap::new(),
        |mut acc, value| {
            acc.entry(value.b.clone()).or_insert(vec![]).push(&value);
            acc
        }
    )
    .collect::<HashMap<String, Vec<&MyStruct>>>();
```

The error I get is

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::vec::Vec<&MyStruct>>: rayon::iter::FromParallelIterator<std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::vec::Vec<&&MyStruct>>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:39:10
   |
39 |         .collect::<HashMap<String, Vec<&MyStruct>>>();
   |          ^^^^^^^ the trait `rayon::iter::FromParallelIterator<std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::vec::Vec<&&MyStruct>>>` is not implemented for `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::vec::Vec<&MyStruct>>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::collections::HashMap<K, V, S> as rayon::iter::FromParallelIterator<(K, V)>>
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62b0946371c576508c511ef7371028c4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [parallel fold documentation](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.1.0/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.fold):

> The **parallel fold** works similarly except that it first breaks up your list into sublists, and hence instead of yielding up a single sum at the end, it yields up multiple sums. The number of results is nondeterministic, as is the point where the breaks occur.

So you want to `reduce` the result of `fold` into one value as final result, not `collect`:

```rust
let result = my_array
    .par_iter()
    .filter_map(|value| value.as_ref().ok())
    .fold(
        || HashMap::new(),
        |mut acc, value| {
            acc.entry(value.b.clone()).or_insert(vec![]).push(value);
            acc
        },
    )
    .reduce(
        || HashMap::new(),
        |m1, m2| {
            m2.iter().fold(m1, |mut acc, (k, vs)| {
                acc.entry(k.clone()).or_insert(vec![]).extend(vs);
                acc
            })
        },
    );
```

[OTOH](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.1.0/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#fold-versus-reduce):

> reduce() requires that the identity function has the same type as the things you are iterating over, and it fully reduces the list of items into a single item

So you can `reduce` into final result in one go:

```rust
let result = my_array
    .par_iter()
    .filter_map(|value| value.as_ref().ok())
    .map(|s| {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert(s.b.clone(), vec![s]);
        m
    })
    .reduce(
        || HashMap::new(),
        |m1, m2| {
            m2.iter().fold(m1, |mut acc, (k, vs)| {
                acc.entry(k.clone()).or_insert(vec![]).extend(vs);
                acc
            })
        },
    );
```

The choice of [`fold` or `map/reduce`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.1.0/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#fold-vs-mapreduce) is up to you.